# "ALERT: Insufficient funds" when deploying a very simple smart contract on Polygon

Tags: remix, metamask, polygon

I am learning how to write and deploy smart contracts on the Polygon network. In Remix, I wrote the following smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.10;

contract HelloWorld {
    uint256 number;

    function store(uint256 num) public {
        number = num;
    }
    
    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return number;
    }
}
```

I compiled the smart contract, set the Injected Web3 environment and connected Metamask. Unfortunately, when I click on Deploy, Metamask says "ALERT: Insufficient funds.", even though the transaction only costs 0.002886 and I have 0.4 MATIC. I tried to use the Test network, too, obtaining the same outcome. Do you know what's happening? I also tried the tutorial at the link https://docs.matic.network/docs/develop/remix/, obtaining the same error.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: where do you have 0.4 matic, on ethereum or on the matic network? how did you connect you metamask to matic?

Comment: I have 0.4 matic in metamask on the matic network. I connected metamask when setting the Injected Web3 environment.

Comment: It’s probably connecting to a wrong network, not other explanations.. can u add some screen shot from remix